Не выводится компонент bitrix:main.ui.grid
Пишу компонент, который добавляет вкладку в сущность компании crm
В этой вкладке есть компонент bitrix:main.ui.grid, который я отображаю, но по не известной человечеству причине, он не выводится
И дело не в том, что он неправильно написан, он написан правильно.
Мой компонент выводится если я зайду в штатную вкладку Битрикса24, там прогрузиться компонент(штатный), тогда после перехода на мою вкладку, мой написанный компонент прогрузиться.
Такое чувство, как-будто моему коду нужна одна строчка, которая разрешает прогрузку компонентов в битрикс24, тогда выведет.
Как работает вкладка?
Я отлавливаю событие onEntityDetailsTabsInitialized - и проверяю, если открыта нужная моя сущность, тогда добавляю свою вкладку, а после перехода на нее с помощью AJAX запроса отображаю свой компонент bitrix:main.ui.grid
$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent('bitrix:main.ui.grid', '', [
    'GRID_ID' => $list_id,
    'COLUMNS' => $columns,
    'ROWS' => $list,
    'SHOW_ROW_CHECKBOXES' => false,
    'AJAX_MODE' => 'Y',
    'AJAX_ID' => \CAjax::getComponentID('bitrix:main.ui.grid', '.default', ''),
    'PAGE_SIZES' =>  [
        ['NAME' => '20', 'VALUE' => '20'],
        ['NAME' => '50', 'VALUE' => '50'],
        ['NAME' => '100', 'VALUE' => '100']
    ],
    'AJAX_OPTION_JUMP'          => 'N',
    'SHOW_CHECK_ALL_CHECKBOXES' => false,
    'SHOW_GRID_SETTINGS_MENU'   => true,
    'SHOW_NAVIGATION_PANEL'     => true,
    'SHOW_PAGINATION'           => true,
    'SHOW_SELECTED_COUNTER'     => true,
    'SHOW_TOTAL_COUNTER'        => true,
    'SHOW_PAGESIZE'             => true,
    'ALLOW_COLUMNS_SORT'        => true,
    'ALLOW_COLUMNS_RESIZE'      => true,
    'ALLOW_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL'   => true,
    'ALLOW_SORT'                => true,
    'ALLOW_PIN_HEADER'          => true,
    'AJAX_OPTION_HISTORY'       => 'N'
]);
?> 


Ответ решился, написал $APPLICATION->ShowHead(); и все заработало
